# Pass video from camera intent to webView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-storage

i am trying to implement a webview that start a video intent, and return the video to a webView.

What i try to do:

**1) Java - add webAppInterface that open video capture intent:**

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(webAppInterface, "Android");
```

---

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    ...
    public void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,10);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
    ...
```

**2) JavaScript - Call it from the webview:**

```
Android.dispatchTakeVideoIntent()
```

**3) Java - Get the Uri, and send path to my webview**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
        wView.loadUrl("javascript:test('" + videoUri.getPath() + "')");
    }
}
```

**4) JavaScript - Get the path in my webView**

```
window.test = (videoUriPath) => {
    ...
}
```

My question is, how to access the video?

And maybe there is a totally different way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the video means I'll suppose playing the video in webView. Have a video element in your HTML (suppose id is 'my-video'), then your javascript will be:

```
window.test = (videoUriPath) => {
 var video = document.getElementById('video');
 var source = document.createElement('source');

 source.setAttribute('src', videoUriPath);

 video.appendChild(source);
 video.load();
 video.play();
}
```

Comment: that didnt work for me...  when i try to play the video i get the next error:

Comment: E/chromium: [ERROR:render_media_log.cc(30)] MediaEvent: MEDIA_ERROR_LOG_ENTRY {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: open context failed"}
E/chromium: [ERROR:render_media_log.cc(30)] MediaEvent: PIPELINE_ERROR DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN

Comment: example of a path that i received in my webView : **/external/video/media/302044**

Comment: It seems chromium has some problem:

https://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/fOI22zC8/media-error-log-entry-pipeline-error-demuxer-error-could-not-open

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454705/chromium-ffmpegdemuxer-open-context-failed-when-playing-audio

One more thing I want to know is that what's the video format you're using?

Comment: See this once if it helps: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13416

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution, its a little overkill, but its working...

**1) JAVA: convert the video to bytes array**

```
byte[] bytes;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];
int bytesRead;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((bytesRead = is.read(data)) != -1) {
   output.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
}
bytes = output.toByteArray();
```

**2) JAVA: send encoded chunks (base64) to the webvView**

```
int startIndex = 0;
int chunkSize= 16384;
while(startIndex < bytes.length){
     byte[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, startIndex, startIndex + chunkSize);
     startIndex = startIndex + chunkSize;
     encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(newArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
     wView.loadUrl("javascript:g_sendFile_f('" + encodedString + "')");
}
wView.loadUrl("javascript:g_sendFile_f('" + "finish" + "')");
```

**3) JAVASCRIPT: receive the encode chunks, combine them, and create blob file**

```
let bytesArrFinal_an = []
window.g_sendFile_f = (msg) =>{
     // last call
     if(msg === "finish"){
         let blob = new Blob(byteArrFinal_an,{type : "video/mp4"})
         this.test_videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         console.log("finish")
         return
      }

      // add bytes to final array
      let bytesArr_an = this.b64toByteArr(msg)
      bytesArrFinal_an = bytesArrFinal_an.concat(bytesArr_an);
      console.log(msg)
}
```

If someone have a more elegant solution i will be happy the see it!